# Name for phenomenom: if if else

Tags: if-statement

Last week I heared about a phenomenom about if-Statements. It had a specific name, but I can't remember it.

The Problem is about an if-if-else construction, for example:

```
if( a!=null )
if( a.isTrue() )
    a.performAction(); 
else
    a.healCondition(); // second chance to do something
```

So the problem comes from missing brackets. It wouldn't be a problem if I use brackets for the outer if.
Without brackets it is not always clear to which "if" the "else" belongs to.

But I don't want to have a solution for that problem. I would be happy to know how this pattern is called.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What language is this? And indentation like your help to see what `if` an `else` belongs to. As for your question, I doubt the "pattern" have any name.

Comment: The language is Java. Thanks for your help. I got the answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ambiguity is called [dangling else](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else), and how it's solved depends on the language. Java for example has syntax rules that associate `else` with the inner `if`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly the phrase I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Java, but what I am saying applies to almost every "bracketed" language.

You should really try not to use multiline if statements when you don't want to use brackets.

In this case you would **not** want to write:

```
 if(a!=null) if(a.isTrue()) a.performAction(); else a.healCondition();
```

It is ugly, so you break it up into multiple lines. As soon as you do that you should add brackets. Not for compiler (which won't need them in this case), but for other programmers and yourself:

```
if(a!=null)
{
  if(a.isTrue()) a.performAction();
  else a.healCondidiont();
}
```

or

```
if(a!=null)
{
  if(a.isTrue())
  {
    a.performAction();
  }
  else
  {
    a.healCondidiont();
  }
}
```